# escape special characters with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I have this password cookie, the password can contain special characters. (I know it is unsafe, but this is for e-learning purposes/workaround)

```
var password = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)password\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

My issue is that it returns the special characters like this e.g:
**! turns out as %21**

I know that I should somehow, escape the special characters using regex, but I just seem not to be able to fix it.

If the password is: **p4sSW0rd!!** it must be returned as: **p4sSW0rd!!** when I for instance alert() it.

Comment: What do you exactly want ?

Comment: `%21` *is* the escape already…!?

Comment: I want the value exactly as follows:
if the password is: p4sSW0rd!!
it must be returned as: p4sSW0rd!! when I for instance alert() it.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('%21') == '!'` u want to decode the string ?

Comment: the actual result of p4sSW0rd!!
is at the moment: p4sSW0rd%21%21

it should be alerted: p4sSW0rd!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%21` is the [URL  / UTF8 encoded value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) of `!`. All you have to do is just decode the value back.

```
function getCookieKeyValue(keyName) { 
    return document.cookie.replace(new RegExp(`(?:(?:^|.*;\\s*)${keyName}\\s*\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$`), "$1"); 
}

// As per your scenario ...
getCookieKeyValue('password'); // p4sSW0rd%21%21 
decodeURIComponent(getCookieKeyValue('password')); // p4sSW0rd!!
```